# dispatching actions within nested functions in redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

When a user submits a form I want them to be prompted with multiple modals.

Basic structure:
My app is set up so that to show a modal all you have to do is dispatch an action with the modal body as the payload fo the action.

`dispatch({type: SHOW_MODAL, payload: <MyModal />})`

When the user submits the form an action is dispatched that is picked up by a saga, so now we are in saga land.  What I'd like to do is have the user be shown several modals sequentially before the form is actually submitted to the backend.

```
// mySaga.js

function* submitForm() {
  // show a modal
  // then show another modal
  // then submit the form
}
```

What is the best way of doing this?  What makes the most sense to me is to use promises.

```
// mySaga.js
function* submitForm() {
 yield call(() => {
   new Promise( resolve => {
     yield put({type: SHOW_MODAL, payload: <MyModal onClick={resolve} />})
   })
 })
 ...
 // add as many more modals as I'd like
 ...
 yield call(myApiCall)
}
```

The problem with the above is that you can't use a yield inside of that promise function because it isn't a generator.  All I need is a way to do a normal dispatch of an action inside of a saga, but in looking all over the internet that does not seem trivial at all.

Am I missing something about sagas?  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to change your program a little.

It is not a good idea to dispatch `<Modal/>` component to store. Although you can store component inside store, but it will be difficult to pass correct `props` to component.

I suggest to have a variable in store, like `firstModalOpened` which will control if modal is showing. You can set this variable in saga and await for an action to change this variable.

```
// mySaga.js
function* submitForm() {
  yield put({type: SHOW_MODAL, firstModalOpened: true});
  take('FIRST_MODAL_CLOSED');   // Await for modal close action
   ...
  // add as many more modals as I'd like
   ...
  yield call(myApiCall)
}
```

In React the `<Modal/>` compoennt can be used as follows

```
<Modal open={props.firstModalOpened} onClose={() => dispatch({type: 'FIRST_MODAL_CLOSED'})}/>
```

If you have several modals which will be opened simultaneously you can call put several times and then await for all close actions to arrive before proceeding to `yield call(myApiCall)`

```
yield put({type: SHOW_MODAL, firstModalOpened: true});
yield put({type: SHOW_MODAL, secondModalOpened: true});
yield all([
  take('FIRST_MODAL_CLOSED')
  take('SECOND_MODAL_CLOSED')
]);
```